# How to get a message from a silent Push notification with OneSignal?

Tags: java, onesignal

In some cases I will need to send some messages and do something on background, I found this exemple on the doc of OneSignal that show how to set up, but I can't see how am I going to get the message that it was sent!

```
public class NotificationExtenderBare extends NotificationExtenderService {
@Override
protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
    OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
    overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
        @Override
        public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {

            // Sets the background notification color to Green on Android 5.0+ devices.
            return builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF00FF00", 16).intValue());
        }
    };

    OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
    // Read properties from result.

    // Return true to stop the notification from displaying.
    return true;
```

Comment: find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. I will update the docs to be more clear.

You can get the message using `receivedResult.payload`

Here is the class definition for `OSNotificationReceivedResult`

```
public class OSNotificationReceivedResult {
   public boolean restoring;

   public boolean isAppInFocus;

   public OSNotificationPayload payload;
}
```

**Edit:** updated [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#section-getting-a-message-payload-from-a-notification) to be more clear, with example code